# Swiping to remove view and to show clickable Button under the Recycylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to do this:  When we swipe from left to right it will remove the particular view, and when we swiping from right to left it  will show a clickable Button under the view.
In this when we swipe from left to right it removes view and when we swipe from right to left it will show buttons but also removes view .

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final Student item = studentList.get(position);

    viewHolder.tvName.setText((item.getName()));
    viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(item.getEmailId());

    viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

    // Drag From Left
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));
    // Drag From Right
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));


    // Handling different events when swiping
    viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
            //when user's hand released
            swipeDelte = true;
            Log.e("TagX", xvel + "");
            Log.e("tagY", yvel + "");
            if (swipeDelte == true && yvel <= 0 && xvel <= 0) {
                Log.e("Item", "Item in ");
                swipeDelte = true;

            } else if (yvel >= 0 && xvel != 0 && xvel > 0) {
                swipeDelte = true;
                Log.e("Item Remove", "item remove");
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                studentList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, studentList.size());
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
//          }
        }
```